# I want to display the correct answer after my question in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel and I am making a quiz app where there are four possible answers of a question and one is correct .The questions and answers are stored in database, my code works properly and got the right result but the problem is it shows all answers after the question.I think it could be done by indexing but don't know how to do this.

**Routes Are :**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::any('/test',function(){

    return view('answerDesk');
});
Route::get('/startQ',[QuestionController::class,'startQ']);
```

**And in my Controller :**

```
class QuestionController extends Controller
{

 
    public function startQ(Request $request){
       
        $users = question::limit(5)->get();
        $answers =$request->answer;
        
        $ans=$request->ans;
        return view('answerDesk',compact('answers','ans','users')); 
    }
}
```

**In my view**

```
<form action="startQ" method="get" role="search">
             @csrf 
            
            @if(isset($users))         
            @foreach($users as $answer) 
            
          <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{$answer->id}}">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">
                   <h4 style=""><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
                    {{$answer->id}}:{{$answer->question}}</h4>
                   </label><br>
                   
       <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->a}}" >(A) : 
        <label  class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->a}}</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->b}}">(B) : 
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->b}}</label><br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->c}}">(C) :
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{$answer->c}}</label><br>
       <input type="radio" name="answer[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->d}}">(D) :
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1"> {{$answer->d}}</label><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="ans[{{$answer->question}}]" value="{{$answer->ans}}">  
        <br>    
         @if(isset($answers)) 
        @foreach($ans as $correct)
        @foreach($answers as $choose)
   
        @if($correct == $choose)
     
        <h6 style="color:green">{{'Correct'}}</h6>
        @break
        @endif
         @endforeach

         @if($correct != $choose)
        
         <h6 style="color:red">{{$correct}}</h6> 
         @continue
         @endif
         
    @endforeach   
@endif

@endforeach 
@endif
        

            <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
           
        </form>
```

can anybody please help me .

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few days ago? Your code to display the answer is placed after the question. just move the code...

Comment: Get the _one_ correct answer in your controller, pass it to the view and display it. No need to foreach through all answers

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mysqli, loops o indexing.. please remove unrelated tags!

Comment: it isn't workikng

Comment: @MFarhanShaukat what is'n working, do you get an error?

Comment: i got  nothing when i try to do this by controller

Comment: First of all: clean up your code before you start debugging: you create a variable `$users` that holds questions. This kind of things will make your application impossible to maintain in the future. Use a query to get the correct answer, and pass it to your view. If you've done that and something "does not work", try to debug it, if you still are stuck ask a clear question with the new code. Also try to avoid multiple nested loops as much as possible.

Comment: ok i'll try to do this

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have bad code structure, try clean this as said Gert B. but

```
@if(isset($answer) && $answer != null )
    {answers block}
@else
    {questions block}
@endif
```

In controller add null check like

```
$answers = $request->answer??null;
```

Comment: its also a solution but i solved it by using my own code with a simple check in my view thank you so much for helping me